# std::function overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, std-function

I've got the following code :

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void foo(function<void(int)>);
void foo(function<void(float, int)>);


void bar(int);
void bar2(float, int);

void dummy()
{
    foo(bar);
    foo(bar2);
}
```

Depending on the different compilers I tried on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ there is an ambiguity error or not...
Who's right ?
What is the most elegant way to solve this issue ?

Comment: This doesn't compile, it is not a complete example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3473.html#2132

Comment: @tillaert it is a complete example. The fact it doesn't compile is his problem.

Comment: This is supposed to be ambiguous in C++11. I think the compilers that succesfully compile the code are applying C++14 rules where the constructor `template<typename F> std::function(F);` doesn't participate in overload resolution if `F` is not callable with the signature of `std::function` that's being constructed.